InvalidCertificate(BadSignature) when using TLS with custom root certificate with rumqttc, rustls
Using rumqttc and rustls, I am trying to connect to a broker that uses a self-signed certificate, however, I get a BadSignature error.
The certificate works with another application (using other language/libraries). I'd really appreciate any help how should go ahead.
Current Behavior
Error on poll: Tls(Io(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificate(BadSignature) })
Code
let mut roots = rustls::RootCertStore::empty();
let file = File::open(cert_path).expect("There was an issue loading the ca certificate file");
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
let certs = rustls_pemfile::certs(&mut reader);
for cert in certs.flatten() {
        roots.add(cert).expect("Could not add ca certificate.");
}

let client_conf = ClientConfig::builder()
        .with_root_certificates(roots.clone())
        .with_no_client_auth();

mqtt_options.set_transport(Transport::tls_with_config(client_conf.into()));

let (client, mut eventloop) = AsyncClient::new(mqtt_options, 10);

loop {
        let notification = eventloop.poll().await.expect("Poll failed.");
}

Certificate
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = DE, ST = <ST>, L = <L>, O = <O>, OU = <OU>, CN = <CN>, emailAddress = <mail>
        Validity
            Not Before: May  3 06:39:54 2021 GMT
            Not After : May  1 06:39:54 2031 GMT
        Subject: C = DE, ST = <ST>, L = <L>, O = <O>, OU = <OU>, CN = <CN>, emailAddress = <mail>
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
                        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
                        ...
                        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
                        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:localhost, DNS:develmqtt.mydomain.com, IP Address:127.0.0.1, IP Address:1.1.1.1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
        ...
        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
        00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:


That looks like anything but a valid certificate.

You are right, I had zeroed out some of the fields. But this is the structure of the certificate.

It turns out that I was provided a server certificate rather than a CA certificate. I don't know how the other application accepted it. With the correct certificate it works!
For anyone who finds himself in the same situation. Use the following command to view the certificate details:
openssl x509 -in <certificate-file> -text -noout
According to my understanding, if you file does not have the following lines, it is not a CA certificate:
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE

